# JQuery to add (math) up values of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form, and I want to only show the last section of the form if the value of all the other inputs is <= 500.  Here is some simple html, mine is slightly more complicated, but it should be the same idea:

```
<div id="addSection">
  <input type="text" id="retire" />  
  <input type="text" id="child" />
  <input type="text" id="military" />
  <input type="text" id="nurse" />
  <input type="text" id="other" /> 
</div>
<div id="random" class="hidden">
<input type="text">  
</div>
```

And here my jQuery that doesn't get close to working :)

```
$('#addSection :input').keyup(function(){        
  $('#addSection').each(function(){
    var totalAmt = 0;
    $(this).find('input').each(function(i,n){
      totalAmt += parseInt($(n).val(), 10)
    });
  });
});

//if totalAmt <= 500 then $('#random').show();
```

Any ideas on how to get it to add as the user goes through the form?  Thanks for the help, if you ahve any questions, I will answer quickly.

Comment: What is wrong with that? Except that you dont need the first `.each`.

Comment: @Karl-AndreGagnon Well, it doesnt seem to work.  I put an alert for totalAmt in different places (inside the loop, after the loop, etc.) and I always get "Nan".  I usually input all 1's into the textboxes

Comment: that would have been a good thing to add in the question ;) David Thomas answer solve that issue.

Comment: @Karl-Andre Sorry about that, got too focused on the question, and forgot to say it didn't work lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#addSection :input').keyup(function(){        
    var totalAmt = 0
  $('#addSection :input').each(function(){
    totalAmt += parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0   

  });
   $('#random').toggle(totalAmt <= 500);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZL3q4/2/

Comment: Please toggle instead of using if. So inelegant

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest (on reviewing and subsequently rewriting my previous attempt):

```
$('#addSection').on('keyup', function(){
    var total = $(this).children().map(function(){
        return parseInt(this.value,10) || 0;
    }).get().reduce(
           function(a, b){
             return  parseInt(a,10) + parseInt(b,10);
           });
    $('#random').toggle(total <= 500);
}).trigger('keyup');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5RKW5/).

References:

- Plain JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- jQuery:

  - [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Quite complex for such a simple thing :)

Comment: True, but beautiful...or, wait: that could just be me and my crazy O_O

Comment: Liking the trigger tho

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="addSection">
    <input type="text" id="retire" />
    <input type="text" id="child" />
    <input type="text" id="military" />
    <input type="text" id="nurse" />
    <input type="text" id="other" />
</div>
<div id="random" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text">
</div>


$('#addSection :input').keyup(function () {
    var totalAmt = 0;
    $('#addSection :input').each(function (i, n) {
        if (parseInt($(n).val(), 10)) totalAmt += parseInt($(n).val(), 10);
    });
    if (totalAmt > 500) $("#random").show();
    else $("#random").hide();
});
```

Comment: Please toggle instead of using if. So inelegant